# Kotlin EAP still in Bintray?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, bintray, jcenter

Bintray end is near but even in the latest Android Studio Arctic Fox the generated repositories include this

`maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }`

Comment: [https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap 502 bad gateway]
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70338843/https-dl-bintray-com-kotlin-kotlin-eap-502-bad-gateway