# https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap 502 bad gateway

Tags: android, kotlin, bintray

My apk is failing to compile saying it could not get

`Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.4.21'] was not found in any of the following sources:`

When I try to visit: https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap I get a 502 bad gateway

is this the reason why it's failing to build?

my gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.4.21'
}

allprojects {
            repositories {
                maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
                maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
                maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven" }
                maven{
                    url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

                }
                maven {
                    url "https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android"
            credentials {
                username 'braintree_team_sdk'
                password 'AKCp8jQcoDy2hxSWhDAUQKXLDPDx6NYRkqrgFLRc3qDrayg6rrCbJpsKKyMwaykVL8FWusJpp'
            }
        }
        maven{
            url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/oss-releases-local'

        }
        jcenter()
        google()

        mavenCentral()

    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

i can't find the reason why my apk suddenly stopped building it was working last month i need to find the solution before tomorrow please someone help me.

full error code

```
Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.4.21'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.4.21')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    maven(https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap)
    MavenRepo
    maven2(https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/)
```

Comment: As @JunYao mention it seems that JCenter is EOL, AndroidStudio tells me this : "JCenter Maven repository is no longer receiving updates: newer library versions may be available elsewhere"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Bintray` and `JCenter` is not supported yet

Remove all `Bintray` and `JCenter` repository configure in your `gradle` file. And use `mavenCentral()` instead.

Here is the solution:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        // jcenter()
        mavenCentral() // use this instead
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.4.21'
}

allprojects {
            repositories {
                maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
                maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
                // maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven" }
                maven{
                    url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

                }
                maven {
                    // url "https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android"
            credentials {
                username 'braintree_team_sdk'
                password 'AKCp8jQcoDy2hxSWhDAUQKXLDPDx6NYRkqrgFLRc3qDrayg6rrCbJpsKKyMwaykVL8FWusJpp'
            }
        }
        maven{
            // url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/oss-releases-local'

        }
        // jcenter()
        google()

        mavenCentral()

    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much but i am still getting the same error ` Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.4.21'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.4.21')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    maven(https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap)
    MavenRepo
    maven2(https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/)`

Answer (score 0):

just go to 'settings.gradle' file and comment
`maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }` line that fixed my problem
how and why I don't know